# getiing null pointer exception in PutMapping

Tags: json, spring-boot, rest, jpa

I have 3 entities User, role and book all bidirectionally connected

user and role->manytomany joinTable(user_roles)

user and book->manytomany joinTable(book_users)

I want the user to issue a book means only update the jointable(book_users) columns

userController

package com.kk.booklendingapi.booklending1.controller;

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rest/user")
public class UserController {
    
    
    @Autowired
    private BookRepository bookRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    
    @GetMapping("/books")
    public List<Book> getBooks(){
        return bookRepository.findAll();
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/books/{bookName}")
    public Book getBooks(@PathVariable String bookName){
        return bookRepository.findByBookName(bookName);
    }
    
    
    //test purpose
    @GetMapping("/users")
    public List<OnlyUsersRequest> getUsers(){
        return userRepository.getOnlyUsers();
    }
    
    @PutMapping("/{userId}")
    public User issueBookByName(@PathVariable int userId,@RequestBody String bookName){
        Optional<User> optionalUser=userRepository.findById(userId);
        User user=optionalUser.get();
        if(user==null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("USer Not Found: "+user);
        }
        System.out.println(user.getUsername());
        System.out.println(bookName+" "+bookName.getClass());
        Book theBook=bookRepository.findByBookName(bookName);
        System.out.println(theBook.getbName());
        
        user.addBook(theBook);
        
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }

}
```

made a custom jpa query in bookrepository that is working fine

```
@GetMapping("/books/{bookName}")
    public Book getBooks(@PathVariable String bookName){
        return bookRepository.findByBookName(bookName);
    }
```

then why i am getting nullpointerexception in putMapping

json url

```
http://localhost:8484/rest/user/2
```

json sending as plain text

```
Angular_Avengers
```

error

```
"java.lang.NullPointerException\r\n\tat com.kk.booklendingapi.booklending1.controller.UserController.issueBookByName(UserController.java:60)\r\n\
```

Comment: What line number is 'Optional<User> optionalUser = ...' in the .UserController source file?

Comment: My guess is that the repo is returning null for the id 2

Comment: `User user = userRepository.findById(userId).orElseThrow(() ->RuntimeException("USer Not Found: "+userId)` You can use above to replace the null check and exception throw

Comment: And line 60 is? Also you should use `map` and `orElseThrow` instead of doing a `get()`  as currently you are using an `Optional` in the wrong way.

Comment: @emeraldjava line no is 52,

Comment: @ThomasAndolf it is returning null Book theBook=bookRepository.findByBookName(bookName); somehow it is not mapping book obj from repo.

Comment: @SSK i am getting the user, i checked with sop and in terminal i am getting the username!!

Comment: @M.Deinum I am getting nullpointerexp before user.addBook(theBook); at line Book theBook=bookRepository.findByBookName(bookName);

Comment: Which indicates that your `bookRepository` is `null`.

Comment: @M.Deinum then how my getMapping is working?? it can fetch book by bookname

Comment: Then line 60 isn't what you are stating it is or the get mapping is in a different controller. Or line 60 is your logging and there is no book being returned.

Comment: @M.Deinum check above both in same controller. line 60 is just i am prinintg the bookname, same as getting null in the book object line

Comment: If there is no book that will lead to a `NullPointerException`. Hence the `bookRepository.findByTitle` returns `null` or in other words there is no book being found. It is your debugging that leads to the error. Instead of `book.getTitle()` just print the `book` and implement a proper `toString` you will then see the `book` is `null`.

Comment: @M.Deinum correct you are. checked with printing the book obj in putmapping. in terminal it is returning null. but oddly it is working in getmapping. it is returning the book object. same line of code in two diff mapping under same controller. what should be the workaround?

Comment: in one i am sending string by pathvariable and second in requestbody

Comment: One has a proper title the other doesn't.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank you sir. Solved. didn't notice i am sending extra spaces in postman in putmapping. must use trim before adding to repo.

Comment: But that should lead you to `NullPointerException`. in this case you will get an empty result.

Comment: @SSK Solved. i was sending bookname with trailing spaces that's why it was not matching with db and returning null

Comment: Yes but it shouldn't result in NullPointerException

Comment: yes jpa query was findByTitle. so if the string doesn't match ,it will not find the respected row from db. so it was assigning null to book obj.hence..